# window.requestFileSystem is always undefined in cordova 3.5

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am trying to access `window.requestFileSystem` in my cordova project I am calling my code like this:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
  alert(window.requestFileSystem);
},true);
```

Alert always comes as undefined, I have following plugins installed: org.apache.cordova.file, org.apache.cordova.file-transfer. This is my Android's res/xml/config.xml file contents:

```
feature name="File">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils" />
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>
<feature name="FileTransfer">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.filetransfer.FileTransfer" />
</feature>
```

Even after doing all these things I am getting alert as `undefined`. I searched a lot in old SO questions but didn't helped me much. I am using Samsung Galaxy S3 neo with Android 4.3. Can someone please help me in this?

Comment: Look carefully through your build logs. Is there anything there that can explain why this plugin isn't available? Reviewing the logcat output during app launch will help too.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget put files inside `www` folder to your cordova project.